# Width auto when using word-break: break-word

Tags: css

How to adjust the width of a `p` tag automatically when using `word-break:break-word` so it equals the needed width for the text?

An example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ehs5v820/

Here the `p` tag should equal about 160px instead of 200px.

Here the related HTML and CSS from the example:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: powderblue;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper p {
  width: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  background-color: mistyrose;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want p to be only as wide as it's content, in this case the text, be? So when it breaks the width gets shorter too?

Comment: Note that your original code had invalid CSS, but valid SCSS/LESS. I converted it manually to CSS. Feel free to rollback or otherwise edit the code yourself.

Comment: Why it should be 160px?

Comment: @Simplicius correct, when the text breaks the width should get shorter too

Comment: `Display: inline;` instead of `width: auto;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `display: inline`.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: powderblue;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper p {
  display: inline;
  word-break: break-word;
  background-color: mistyrose;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <p>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted. However you can now remove `width: auto;`, since it has no effect anymore.